# Which true way to create several classes with default values inheritable from other class and use one general behaivor init

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try this way,

```
def build_car_from_dict(car_dict):
    marque = car_dict.get('marque')
    marque_class = CarMarqueCollection.get(marque)
    if marque_class:
        return marque_class(car_dict)
    else:
        return CarDict(car_dict)


class CarDict(dict):
    def __new__(cls, car_dict=None):
        if car_dict is None and hasattr(cls, 'DEFAULT'):
            car_dict = cls.DEFAULT
        return super().__new__(dict, car_dict)


class BersedesMenzCar(CarDict):
    DEFAULT = {'marque': 'Bersedes-Menz', 'wheels': 4, 'doors': 3}
    def signal(self):
       print('beep')


class YototaCar(CarDict):
    DEFAULT = {'marque': 'Yotota', 'wheels': 4, 'doors': 5}
    def signal(self):
       print('beep-beeeeee')


class LevrocheCar(CarDict):
    DEFAULT = {'marque': 'Levroche', 'wheels': 5, 'doors': 3}
    def signal(self):
       print('beep-beep')


CarMarqueCollection = {
    'Bersedes-Menz': BersedesMenzCar,
    'Yotota': YototaCar,
    'Levroche': LevrocheCar
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    some_dict = {}
    build_car_from_dict(some_dict)
```

but it's not right to check class field `'DEFAULT'` and use them in parent class. 
If override `__init__` in each marque class like this:

```
class YototaCar(CarDict):
def __init__(self, car_dict=None):
    if car_dictis None:
        car_dict= self.DEFAULT
    super().__init__(car_dict)
```

It is not suitable for DRY practice. Code will be repeated in each class.
How to organize this code according to SOLID and DRY practices?

Comment: why are you inheriting from `dict`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga behavior of marque classes must be like dictionary

Comment: why must it be a subclass? Why not various dict objects? And what do you mean by this "but it's not right to check class field 'DEFAULT' and use them in parent class."? Why is it not right?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "why must it be a subclass? Why not various dict objects?" - marque classes will have different behaviors. "Why is it not right?" - it will be work but,i think parent class must don't know anything about classes that inherit from it. Am I wrong?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was wrong it will not be worked, and I found solution

Answer (score 0):

To resolve that need just move check `DEFAULT` from `__new__` method to `___init__`. Like that:

```
class CarDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, car_dict=None):
        if car_dict is None and hasattr(self, 'DEFAULT'):
            car_dict = self.DEFAULT
        return super().__init__(car_dict)
```